# Spark need of HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

Hi can anyone explain me, does Apache 'Spark Standalone' need HDFS?

If it's required how Spark uses the HDFS block size during the Spark application execution.
I mean am trying to understand what will be the HDFS role during Spark application execution.

Spark documentation says that the processing parallelism is controlled through RDD partitions and the executors/cores.

Can anyone please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Spark can work without any issues without using HDFS and most certainly it is not required for core execution.

Some distributed storage (not necessarily HDFS) is required for checkpoiniting and is useful for saving results.